Excluding Contacts from a Journey in SFMC SQL Query Based on Another Journey
I have a situation where I want to exclude contacts from one journey in SFMC if they have been in another journey 'X'. I thought the best way to do this would be by excluding contacts who received an email from journey 'X'.
My question is: In this scenario, is it better to verify if someone was in journey 'X' by checking the TriggerSendCustomerKey (I will have it as it is the external key in tracking in Email Studio) or by using JobId and subscriberKey?
I'm wondering which method would be more reliable or efficient. Could anyone share their experience or advice on this?

To manage exclusion from one journey based on participation in another journey, using Update Contact activities to track when a customer enters and exits a journey is a ideal approach, I believe. Here’s how we have implemented this with SQL queries. We will take an example of Journey X and Journey Y

Track Journey Entry and Exit: Use Update Contact activities in Journey X and Journey Y to log when a contact enters and exits the journey. You would have a Data Extension for each journey to store this information (e.g., [JourneyX_EntryDE] and [JourneyY_EntryDE]).

Exclusion Query: To suppress contacts who are currently in Journey X (those who entered but haven’t exited yet) from Journey Y, you will need to write SQL queries to identify the suppress list and apply it in Journey Y


Data Extension for Journey X:
Let’s assume the structure of the Data Extension [JourneyX_EntryDE] is like this:

SubscriberKey (Primary Key)
EmailAddress
EntryDate (Date the contact entered Journey X)
ExitDate (Date the contact exited Journey X, null if they haven’t exited)

Identify Contacts in Journey X (Not Yet Exited):
SELECT 
    SubscriberKey, 
    EmailAddress
FROM 
    [JourneyX_EntryDE]
WHERE 
    EntryDate IS NOT NULL 
    AND ExitDate IS NULL

Exclude Contacts from Journey Y
SELECT 
    y.SubscriberKey, 
    y.EmailAddress
FROM 
    [JourneyY_EntryDE] y
WHERE 
    y.SubscriberKey NOT IN (
        SELECT x.SubscriberKey 
        FROM [JourneyX_EntryDE] x
        WHERE x.EntryDate IS NOT NULL 
        AND x.ExitDate IS NULL
    )

So while creating entryDe for each journey, we take care of the suppression.
